# From Login page to Profile page

Tags: php, authentication, profile, member

I did some research here in stackoverflow, but couldn't find the same problem. I have a login page and when the user logs in, it is redirected to profile page. In the profile page  I want to print the name of the user. I am including the file login.php, but I feel for some reason the variable, which contains the username can't be used from login.php in the profile.php. Here is the code:

**Login page**

```
<?php
        $host = "XXXX";
        $username = "XXXX";
        $password = "XXXX";
        $db = "XXXX";

        $conn = new mysqli($host, $username,$password, $db);

        if($conn->connect_error){
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display error', 1);

        if(isset($_POST["loginButton"])){
                $loginUsername = $_POST["loginUsername"];
                $loginPassword = $_POST["loginPassword"];              
                $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$loginUsername' and password='$loginPassword'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
                $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                if ($count == 1){
                        header("Location:profile.php");
                }else{
                echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";
                }
        }
?>
```

**Profile page**

```
<?php
include("login.php");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display error', 1);

echo $loginUsername;

$sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = '$loginUsername' "; 
$result = mysqli_connect($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $username = $row["username"];
```

Comment: can you post the code on stack overflow?

Comment: After the redirect, the `$_POST` values are wiped, because that redirect isn't a post. I think you want to learn about some `sessions` now.

Answer (score 1):

You are reloading the page. Value of `$loginUsername` is not kept.
In your case you could try using session

in your login assign username to session:

```
if ($count == 1){
 $_SESSION['username'] = $loginUsername;
 header("Location:profile.php");
}
```

in your profile, use the session:

```
echo $_SESSION['username']
```

don't forget to start session in the beginning of your pages like `session_start();`

[about session](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: @kaloian mateev if this helped, feel free to press tick icon

Answer (score 0):

**You need to learn about [PHP SESSION](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp):** You can simply done this with this.

```
<?php


        $host = "localhost";
        $username = "user_root";
        $password = "010203";
        $db = "game_db";

        $conn = new mysqli($host, $username,$password, $db);

        if($conn->connect_error){

                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

        }


        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display error', 1);


        if(isset($_POST["loginButton"])){

                $loginUsername = $_POST["loginUsername"];
                $loginPassword = $_POST["loginPassword"];


                $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$loginUsername' and password='$loginPassword'";

                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
                $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                if ($count == 1){
                       session_start();
                       $_SESSION['loginUsername'] =  $loginUsername;
                        header("Location:profile.php");


                }else{
                echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";
                }



        }



?>
```

And use this in any page with session.

```
<?php
session_start();
            include("login.php");
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            ini_set('display error', 1);
           $loginUsername = $_SESSION['loginUsername'];
            echo $loginUsername;

                    $sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = '$loginUsername' ";

                                            $result = mysqli_connect($conn,$sql);

                                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

                                                    echo $username = $row["username"];
```

Comment: Yes, I read about them now and it works. I don't understand when to destroy session and what it does exactly?

Comment: you can set a logout link to a logout page. and on that you can destroy your session and redirect to your login page.